# How to install curses gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, curses, pdcurses

How to install [curses](https://github.com/ruby/curses) gem on Windows?

I already tried to do everything mentioned in the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934524/installing-ncurses-for-ruby-on-windows) question and still got the same error:

```
>E:\software\Ruby22\bin\gem install curses
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curses:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    E:/software/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160411-12372-2bgdm1.rb extconf.rb
checking for tgetent() in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent() in -ltermcap... no
checking for ncurses.h... no
checking for ncurses/curses.h... no
checking for ncursesw/curses.h... no
checking for curses_colr/curses.h... no
checking for curses.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=E:/software/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-curses-dir
        --without-curses-dir
        --with-curses-include
        --without-curses-include=${curses-dir}/include
        --with-curses-lib
        --without-curses-lib=${curses-dir}/lib
        --with-ncurses-dir
        --without-ncurses-dir
        --with-ncurses-include
        --without-ncurses-include=${ncurses-dir}/include
        --with-ncurses-lib
        --without-ncurses-lib=${ncurses-dir}/lib
        --with-termcap-dir
        --without-termcap-dir
        --with-termcap-include
        --without-termcap-include=${termcap-dir}/include
        --with-termcap-lib
        --without-termcap-lib=${termcap-dir}/lib
        --with-tinfolib
        --without-tinfolib
        --with-termcaplib
        --without-termcaplib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in E:/software/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/curses-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to E:/software/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/curses-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: The messages are clear: the script looks for certain headers and libraries, does not find them, and suggests you look at the logfile.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39950423